# Is there a way to pass a method CALL in C#? (not generic-function/delegate types)

Tags: c#, function, methods

**Background**

I would like to build a queue of work with some methods that need to be performed. I would like to add the following 6 methods to a queue of work and then perform them until the queue is exhausted.

```
// method call #1
InputConfiguration("discrete input");

// method call #2
Thread.Sleep(100);

// method call #3
DisconnectFromGround("pin 8");

// method call #4
CheckForPause();

// method call #5
ConnectPins(7, 8);

// method call $6
DisconnectPin(9);
```

**Question**

Is there any such structure/class I can use that will account for all of the different parameters and method calls?

Comment: Could you use an array of `Action`?

Comment: Why are you forbidding generic functions and delegate types?

Comment: @DStanley I've got over 3000 EXACT things I have to do, all of which are completely different.

Comment: @Stevie?  OK, so?  Create an `Action` for each one by wrapping it in a lambda (`() => InputConfiguration("discrete input");`) and call them in sequence, calling other stuff between if necessary.  Or are you just unclear how to call a collection of `Action`s in order?

Comment: How are you defining the 3000 tasks, some config file? Something that could change at run time?

Comment: Write your actions as a language. Parse lines, do what the line says should be done, then do whatever else. Although you *can* achieve what you want as method calls (`Delegate.Invoke` would be your friend) this isn't very clean. Or reliable, for that matter. I'm assuming those 3000 things reduce to a handful of action types with different parameters, not literally 3000 different methods.

Comment: @BradChristie Something absolutely ridiculous that I won't have time to get into.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I wish, but they are all completely different, random things.

Comment: @StevieV: I ask because I am looking to see if it's acceptable to compile the steps when you build the program, or if it needs to be flexible enough to change without a recompilation.

Comment: @BradChristie I've tried JSON, I've tried XML, I've tried getting this thing to be refactored into smaller work... It just won't work, there are too many different things with no flexibility at all.

Comment: @StevieV: Let me try to clarify--It looks like you're (essentially) building a pipeline of sorts; something that can process data sequentially and synchronously, but could contain many steps. I can think of a few possible ways, but need to know if these steps are constant (such as business logic hard-coded) or could be altered later on (such as being defined via an outside source, regardless of method). Either is fine, I'm just trying to understand the requirement.

Comment: How about `DataFlow` ? http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html

Comment: Without getting too deep, I'd be looking at either `Task.ContinueWith` (where you can pass off processed portions to the next step) or a `BufferBlock<T>` (if you pas along a single object to be processed and manipulated).

Comment: @BradChristie What you've said there pretty much sums it up. The software is hard-coded into the spec and needs to be followed exactly. The steps are exactly constant, the only reason I want to put this into a queue is so that I can check for pauses/stops between all of the random/craziness that is happening.

Comment: @StevieV While it's pretty clear what kind of code you are aiming for, it is less clear what the actual task is without giving more details (a lot more details) on what the code (in an abstract manner) has to accomplish (without going into C# at first). So that you can get a better answer and not have 100 ppl asking questions because no one really gets it. The only thing we know atm is that you want a queue and need to call 3000 methods. But why is that? What do these methods do? It's a black box for me. If you don't have time to explain, then answer below is best you'll get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you don't need a return value, an `Action` would fit the bill.

```
List<Action> yourQueue = new List<Action>();
yourQueue.Add(() => InputConfiguration("discrete input"));
yourQueue.Add(() => Thread.Sleep(100));
// And so on.
```

Perhaps instead of creating "a queue" of work, why not just write a new method? You will get the *best* performance that way.

Comment: I've got literally over 3000 methods I need to perform sequentially in an exact order, and every single one takes different parameters. In between each call I need to check on some other stuff.

Comment: @StevieV That doesn't explain why the answer won't work.

Comment: @StevieV it sounds like you need to refactor in into smaller methods for "units of work"

Comment: @DanielA.White Tell me about it, add an answer if that's what you think.

Comment: @StevieV that's a separate question - it might be better for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DanielA.White Maybe I'll put something up there at some point after this expires. In any case, if you have something to add then feel free.